# Last row offset within a filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter

So the purpose of my macro is to add a version number to a part number. First a user will input all the data then my macro will create a new entry with that information at the bottom of the table. Then it will filter the table based on part number. Still within the filter I need it to look at the previous entry and add 1 for my current entry. For example if the previous was 01 the next would need to be 02 and so on. I am running into trouble getting my macro to run the add 1 part below is my code. I am thinking that it may not be possible within a filter or I have to write my code differently. Any insight would be awesome thanks!

```
    'Update version number
 Sheets("New Version ").Select
    part = Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("PN_List").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B1:B3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Worksheets("PN_List").Activate
With Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Value = "0" & .Offset(-1).Value + 1
    End With
```

Comment: "I am running into trouble getting my macro to run the add 1" -- what exactly is the trouble?

Comment: The trouble is that it does take the last entry and add plus one to the current entry

Comment: When I run the last `With` block from your code it places a new value just below the bottom-most cell in column B, and the new value is +1 of the value in the preceding preceding row. The only issue I can see is the leading 0 is not preserved, which you can solve by adding `.NumberFormat = "@"` between the `With` declaration and the `.Value` statement.

Comment: Hello Andy can you please show me what my new code would look like with your updates. Thanks!

Comment: what you want is possible within a filter :D. I assumed that you filter Column A for the part number. When all the part numbers are displayed, the last entry have no value in it's adjacent cell in Column B. So you need to add value to it equal to the previous value in the filter + 1. Your approach will not work because you're not working on the visible ranges only but with all the range. Your code will run but you'll not get the expected result. See my post for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's re-write your code a bit.

```
Dim wsNewVersion = Thiwworkbook.Sheets("New Version")
Dim wsPNList = Thiwworkbook.Sheets("PN_List")

part = wsNewVersion.Range("B4").Value

wsPNList.Range("A1:K3000").AutoFilter Field:= 1, Criteria1:=part
wsPNList.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
wsPNList.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
wsPNList.Range("B1:B3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
:=xlSortNormal
With wsPNList.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'~~> Below code is what you need i guess

Dim myrng As Range, lrow As Long
Dim myadd

'~~> Get the Range Address of the visible cells only
lrow = wsPNList.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrng = wsPNList.Range("B1", Range("B" & lrow)).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'~~> pass addresses in array
myadd = Split(myrng.Address, ",")

'~~> Now you know the address, you can assign the value
With wsPNList
    .Range(myadd(UBound(myadd))).Value = Range(myadd(UBound(myadd) - 1)).Value + 1
End With
```

Hope this is what you need.
I believe it is :) but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your cell is formatted as "General"

Right-click the cell, go to Format Cells. Change the Category to "text"

or, if you want it done within VBA, add this:

```
.Value = "0" & .Offset(-1).Value + 1
.Style = "Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Per request:

```
'Update version number
Sheets("New Version ").Select
part = Range("B4").Value
Sheets("PN_List").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("B1:B3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PN_List").AutoFilter.Sort
  .Header = xlYes
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
Worksheets("PN_List").Activate
With Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  ' following line was added to set text format in the target cell
  .NumberFormat = "@"
  .Value = "0" & .Offset(-1).Value + 1
End With
```